# Apache 301 redirect while preserving parts of URL

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to write a 301 Apache redirect and preserve a portion of the URL?

For example, I have pages that include -md in the title and want to redirect them to the same URL just without the trailing -md. I want to preserve the test-page-1 and test-page-2 portion, but I'm unsure how to write the Rewrite rule to achieve this.

/doctors/test-page-1-md ---> /pages/test-page-1
/doctors/test-page-2-md ---> /pages-test-page-2

1. How would I write the rewrite rule to look for the /test-page-1-md after the /doctors?
2. How would I preserve the test-page-1 and test-page-2 portions?

I've been working with this to start but I don't appear to be having much luck. I think my problem lies with the $1 variables.

```
RewriteRule ^doctors/$1-md           /doctors/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [RewriteRule syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> RewriteRule *Pattern* *Substitution* [*flags*]

Pattern is a perl compatible regular expression. The Substitution of a rewrite rule is the string that replaces the original URL-path that was matched by Pattern. So, in order to use `$1` variable in *Substitution*, you first need to match it in *Pattern* :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^doctors/(.+)-md /pages/$1 [R=302]
```

(the above should work in .htaccess; if you use it in VirtualHost configuration, you have to start the Pattern with leading `/`, so: `^/doctors/(.+)-md`). You can also change 302 to 301 once you are sure that everything is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks Dusan! Looks great! So for apache redirects like this we can use any perl compatible regex and the server will understand it?